# Wrap a loosely typed interface and make it strongly typed

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

There is an external API that I have to use with the following signature:

```
class Item {
    String type;
    String name;
    ///...setters, getters
}

interface ItemFinder {
     List<Item> getItemsByType(String type);
}
```

In my application,

If I call `getItemsByType("vegetables")`, then I receive `List(Item(type="vegetables", name="Lettuce"), Item(type="vegetables", name="Tomato"))`

If I call `getItemsByType("berries")`, then I receive `List(Item(type="berries", name="Strawberry"), Item(type="berries", name="Cranberry"))`

If I call `getItemsByType("shapes")`, then I receive `List(Item(type="shapes", name="Square"), Item(type="shapes", name="Triangle"))`
etc... and there are dozens of types like this.

I want to avoid common type errors, I.e. avoid assigning berries to vegetables.

What is the best way to wrap this loosely typed interface, to make it more strongly typed? I.e. what is the best way to implement something like the following:

```
class Vegetable /* maybe extends something ? */ {
    String name;
}
class Berry /* maybe extends something ? */ {
    String name;
}
class Shape /* maybe extends something ? */ {
    String name;
}
...
List<Berry> berries = getStronglyTyped(Berry.class); // maybe some factory here instead of a class ?
```

The question is how to implement `getStronglyTyped()` method efficiently, with clean code, avoiding hacks etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "best way"? What criterion are you using to judge which way is the *best*?

Comment: Why are you making it strongly typed if all the items have the same fields anyway? What advantage are you getting here?

Comment: @Sweeper Type safety. So that I don't assign oranges to vegetables.

Comment: What is wrong with `getStronglyTyped(Berry.class)` ??? That is exactly what eg. Jackson does.

Comment: The question is how to implement this getStronglyTyped method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make that mapping somehow. The logical place is when mapping your `Item` instances to `Fruit` instances:

(pseudo code, but you should get the idea)

```
items.stream()
  .map { it -> switch(it.type) {
    case "vegetables" -> new Vegetable(it.name)
    case "berries" -> new Berry(it.name)
    // etc 
    default: /* TBD */
  }
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This won't compile, you can't return different types from a method.
If we make `Vegetable` and `Berry` extend some common abstract class like `Item` then this method will have to return generic List<Item> and we are back to square one.

Comment: Like I said, it's pseudo code. Once the list is created, you can filter on type, and that's really all you need.

Answer (score 0):

A simple idea is to put everything in `Map`s, including the type name used for the original API, and how to create the strongly-typed items.

You'd have two maps:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, String> typeNames = Map.of(
        Vegetable.class, "vegetables",
        Berry.class, "berries",
        Shape.class, "shapes"
);

private static final Map<Class<?>, Function<String, ?>> constructors = Map.of(
        // assuming constructors that take the item's name exist
        Vegetable.class, Vegetable::new,
        Berry.class, Berry::new,
        Shape.class, Shape::new
);
```

You can also combine the type name and the `Function<String, ?>` into a class - then you'd only need one map:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
class ItemInfo {
    private final String typeName;
    private final Function<String, ?> factory;
}

private static final Map<Class<?>, ItemInfo> knownItemTypes = ...
```

And then use the `Class<T>` parameter that `getStronglyTyped` takes to access the maps:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> List<T> getStronglyTyped(Class<T> type, ItemFinder finder) {
    var typeName = typeNames.get(type);
    if (typeName == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unknown type!");
    }
    return (List<T>)finder.getItemsByType(typeName).stream().map(
            x -> constructors.get(type).apply(x.getName())
    ).toList();
}
```

You can also create a (sealed) interface that `Vegetable`, `Fruit` and `Shape` implement, and constrain `T` to that, for extra safety.

Answer (score 0):

Item class

```
   abstract class Item {
        private final String name;
        public Item(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() + "{name:´" + name + "´}";
        }
    }
```

Berry class

```
public class Berry extends Item {
    public Berry(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Shape class

```
public class Shape extends Item {
    public Shape(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Vegetable class

```
public class Vegetable extends Item{
    public Vegetable(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    private static final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            new Vegetable("Lettuce"),
            new Vegetable("Tomato"),
            new Berry("Strawberry"),
            new Berry("Cranberry"),
            new Shape("Square"),
            new Shape("Triangle")
    ));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Shape> shapes = getItemsByType(Shape.class);
        System.out.println(shapes);
        List<Berry> berries = getItemsByType(Berry.class);
        System.out.println(berries);
        List<Vegetable> vegetables = getItemsByType(Vegetable.class);
        System.out.println(vegetables);
    }


    public static <T extends Item> List<T> getItemsByType(Class<T> tClass) {
        return items.stream()
                .filter(item -> item.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(tClass.getSimpleName()))
                .map(tClass::cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Output

`[Shape{name:´Square´}, Shape{name:´Triangle´}]`
`[Berry{name:´Strawberry´}, Berry{name:´Cranberry´}]`
`[Vegetable{name:´Lettuce´}, Vegetable{name:´Tomato´}]`